# Fluent sorting of a List<T> on multiple criteria using extension methods?

Tags: c#, sorting, extension-methods

To sort a List on multiple criteria, I'm currently doing something like:

```
collection.Sort((f1, f2) =>
{
    var comp = f1.FirstCriteria.CompareTo(f2.FirstCriteria);
    return comp != 0 ? comp : f1.SecondCriteria.CompareTo(f2. SecondCriteria);
});
```

But wouldn't it be nice to be able to do something like:

```
collection.MultipleSort(f1.FirstCriteria, f2.FirstCriteria)
          .Then(f1.SecondCriteria, f2.SecondCriteria)
```

Any ideas for a good implementation of a fluent interface for sorting?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You mean something like the following?

```
using System.Linq;

collection.OrderBy(t => t.FirstCriteria).ThenBy(t => t.SecondCriteria);
```

Comment: Now why didn't google bring that one up! :-) I should read more books before asking questions!

Comment: The only question would then be how to do descending?

Comment: @Hainsey, How about OrderByDescending and ThenByDescending?

Comment: @Hainsey, I wouldn't worry about missing it too much.  To me Linq extensions aren't always the most discoverable things.  But the nice thing is, once you discover it, you don't forget it :>

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that it sounds like you want to do an *in place* sort; in which case, you'd need to know (with a fluent API) when you've finished adding conditions. This contrasts to the LINQ approach, because that uses deferred execution.

For single condition sorts, you can use something like:

```
public static void Sort<TSource, TValue>(this List<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, TValue> selector) {
    var comparer = Comparer<TValue>.Default;
    source.Sort((x,y)=>comparer.Compare(selector(x),selector(y)));
}
public static void SortDescending<TSource, TValue>(this List<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, TValue> selector) {
    var comparer = Comparer<TValue>.Default;
    source.Sort((x,y)=>comparer.Compare(selector(y),selector(x)));
}
```

It would be harder with multiple sorts; you can't use `params` because each `TValue` may be different. You'd probably need to either use a terminator step and an intermediary "builder" class (essentially writing a DSL), or you'd need to construct the comparer separately first.